# PHP not communicating with MYSQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just looking at some coding for how auction sites work (behind the scene and I'm going to be starting up my own later on) so I gave this free one a- go , however I've had a look through the code yet cant figure out why it isn't working!

Hopefully you guys can help me out here :\

```
<?php
002
/***************************************************************************
003
*   copyright              : (C) 2008 - 2013 WeBid
004
*   site                   : http://www.webidsupport.com/
005
***************************************************************************/
006

007
/***************************************************************************
008
*   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
009
*   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
010
*   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
011
*   (at your option) any later version. Although none of the code may be
012
*   sold. If you have been sold this script, get a refund.
013
***************************************************************************/
014

015 session_start();
016 include 'functions.php';
017 define('InInstaller', 1);
018

019 $main_path = getmainpath();
020 $thisversion = this_version();
021 echo print_header(false);
022

023 $step = (isset($_GET['step'])) ? $_GET['step'] : 0;
024 switch($step)
025 {
026    case 2:
027        $siteURL = urldecode($_GET['URL']);
028        $siteEmail = $_GET['EMail'];
029        include '../includes/config.inc.php';
030        include 'sql/dump.inc.php';
031        $queries = count($query);
032        if (!mysql_connect($DbHost, $DbUser, $DbPassword))
033        {
034            die('<p>Cannot connect to ' . $DbHost . '</p>');
035
    }
036        if (!mysql_select_db($DbDatabase))
037        {
038            die('<p>Cannot select database</p>');
039        }
040        echo ($_GET['n'] * 25) . '% Complete<br>';
041        $from = (isset($_GET['from'])) ? $_GET['from'] : 0;
042        $fourth = floor($queries/4);
043        $to = ($_GET['n'] == 4) ? $queries : ($fourth * $_GET['n']);
044        for ($i = $from; $i < $to; $i++)
045        {
046            mysql_query($query[$i]) or die(mysql_error() . "\n\t" . $query[$i]);
047        }
048        flush();
049
    if ($i < $queries)
050
    {
051 echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "install.php?    
step=2&URL=' . urlencode($_GET['URL']) . '&EMail=' . $_GET['EMail'] . '&cats=' .          $_GET['cats'] . '&n=' . ($_GET['n'] + 1) . '&from=' . $i . '";</script>';
052
    }
053        else
054        {
055            echo '<p>Installation complete.</p>
056                <p>What do I do now?</p>
057
            <ul>
058                    <li>Your WeBid password salt: <span style="color: #FF0000; font-    weight:bold;">' . $_SESSION['hash'] . '</span> You should make note of this random code, it     is used to secure your users passwords. It is stored in your config file if you accidently delete this file and don\'t have this code all your users will have to reset their passwords</li>
059                    <li>Remove the install folder from your server. You will not be     able to use WeBid until you do this.</li>
060                    <li>Finally set-up your admin account <a href="' . $_GET['URL']  . 'admin/" style="font-weight:bold;">here</a></li>
061                    <li>Maybe check out our <a href="http://www.webidsupport.com/forums/">support forum</a></li>
062                </ul>';
063        }
064        break;
065    case 1:
066        if (!mysql_connect($_POST['DBHost'], $_POST['DBUser'], $_POST['DBPass']))
067        {
068            die('<p>Cannot connect to ' . $DbHost . ' with the supplied username and password. <a href="#" onclick="history.go(-1)">Go Back</a></p>');
069        }
070        if (!mysql_select_db($_POST['DBName']))
071        {
072            die('<p>Cannot select database ' . $_POST['DBName'] . '. <a href="#" onclick="history.go(-1)">Go Back</a></p>');
073        }
074        $cats = (isset($_POST['importcats'])) ? 1 : 0;
075        echo '<b>Step 1:</b> Writing config file...<br>';
076        $path = (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $_POST['mainpath']) : $_POST['mainpath'];
077        $hash = md5(microtime() . rand(0,50));
078        $_SESSION['hash'] = $hash;
079        // generate config file
080        $content = '<?php' . "\n";
081        $content .= '$DbHost     = "' . $_POST['DBHost'] . '";' . "\n";
082        $content .= '$DbDatabase = "' . $_POST['DBName'] . '";' . "\n";
083        $content .= '$DbUser     = "' . $_POST['DBUser'] . '";' . "\n";
084        $content .= '$DbPassword = "' . $_POST['DBPass'] . '";' . "\n";
085        $content .= '$DBPrefix  = "' . $_POST['DBPrefix'] . '";' . "\n";
086        $content .= '$main_path = "' . $path . '";' . "\n";
087        $content .= '$MD5_PREFIX = "' . $hash . '";' . "\n";
088        $content .= '?>';
089        $output = makeconfigfile($content, $path);
090        if ($output)
091        {
092            $check = check_installation();
093            if ($check)
094            {
095                echo '<p>You appear to already have an installation on WeBid running would you like to do a <a href="update.php">upgrade instead?</a></p>';
096            }
097            echo 'Complete, now to <b><a href="?step=2&URL=' . urlencode($_POST['URL']) . '&EMail=' . $_POST['EMail'] . '&cats=' . $cats . '&n=1">step 2</a></b>';
098        }
099        else
100        {
101            echo 'WeBid could not automatically create the config file, please could you enter the following into config.inc.php (this file is located in the includes directory)';
102            echo '<p><textarea style="width:500px; height:500px;">
103'.$content.'
104            </textarea></p>';
105            echo 'Once you\'ve done this, you can continue to <b><a href="?step=2&URL=' . urlencode($_POST['URL']) . '&EMail=' . $_POST['EMail'] . '&cats=' . $cats . '&n=1">step 2</a></b>';
106        }
107        break;
108    default:
109        $check = check_installation();
110
    if ($check)
111        {
112            echo '<p>You appear to already have an installation on WeBid running would you like to do a <a href="update.php">upgrade instead?</a></p>';
113        }
114        echo show_config_table(true);
115    break;
116}
117 
118 ?>
```

but on the front end I'm getting this error

```
WeBid Installer v1.1.1


Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is     known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\WeBid\install\install.php on line 66

Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\WeBid\install\install.php on line 66

Notice: Undefined variable: DbHost in C:\xampp\htdocs\WeBid\install\install.php on line 68
Cannot connect to with the supplied username and password. Go Back
```

whats the problem here?
I've put in the username and password for sa User - however its still saying its the wrong username/password - thought I know its the correct username and password for it.

Any help would be awesome!

Edit - is that the only thing thats stopping it communicating with it - the username and password - if so , does anybody know how to add a new user to the new DB that I can change username and password to get it working?

Comment: The error is no a username/password, it cannot find the host from some $_POST data, then it is trying to 'die()' and using a variable $DBHost in the error message (which isn't set anywhere else) so it's not failing there properly.

Comment: Why all the numbered code lines; did you take that off a Website somewhere and just pasted it here?

Comment: @Fred-ii- as I said I'm just looking at some coding for how auction sites work (behind the scene and I'm going to be starting up my own later on) so I gave this free one a- go"

Comment: If you get downvoted, it would `not` have come from me (*just saying*) numbers throw me off. I'm just wondering why you included all the numbers for the coded lines.

Comment: @chuck You got downvoted by me I'm afraid, I've posted an answer which (hopefully) explains why.

Comment: You have `DBHost` yet using `$DbHost` --- two different animals altogether. Letter-case is important. I'm just having a bit of hard time following your code, as to what is what. It's a wall of code and trying to find the missing piece to a puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

I started this as a comment but, wow this script is .....wow.

The error is no a username/password, it cannot find the host from some $_POST data, then it is trying to 'die()' and using a variable $DBHost in the error message (which isn't set anywhere else) so it's not failing there properly.

When it eventually does die it dies at the  username/password error but that is being generated not because the username/password is wrong but because the connection was never started.

Now onto the real issue, if this script exists on a server that is on the internet, I could probably use it to hack the site  db in about 10 mins flat, in fact (if i had the usernames and passwords) I could use your script to output someone elses db. Why on earth are you passing DB login info via POST data? I hope at the least your are using HTTPS to do so.

Overall this script is a mess, it's clear it was copypasted together and slightly modified without any real understanding. I'm sorry if that is harsh but without understanding what is happening when you put several pieces of code together without knowing what they do **properly** you open yourself up to the kinds of errors you are getting.

You are not escaping/cleaning variables, you have spaghetti code with if/else  nested within switch conditionals.

Again I apologise if I am coming across as harsh and I understand we all have to start somewhere and that sometimes learning is difficult due to outdated information but with coding you **need** to understand some basics before you start.

Please at least give this site a look through http://www.phptherightway.com/

Comment: thats all good mate , as I said , I am just having a look at how they work as I am interested in potentially building my own , I'm not going to be using this one as it is - I would modify it to be better, but I am just using this as a learning curve , so any and all help is appreciated

Comment: @chuck I wouldn't just modify this one. I would throw it out and start again.

Answer (score -1):

You have used `$dbhost` variable which have not been defined with a value. So if you check that properly it will work.

Comment: What do you recommend I make the variable too ?

Comment: @chuck just set it to "localhost"